# Nestjs execution after pipe but before the method handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, design-patterns, nestjs

Can I add any execution after all pipes transform but before the method handler?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There's no enhancers that run after all the pipes but before the handler. The *closest* you could get is another pipe. Once all the pipes are finished though, Nest will immediately call the route handler

Comment: Just because I want to add some executions check authorization (guard) but it needs to be validated (pipe transform) before. I understood that breaks the framework structure but I'm looking for a workaround.
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/767#issue-329979578

Comment: You can run the transformation yourself inside the guard. That's about it though